# Can't remove element from list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in Unity, and I want to remove an element from a list. But when I call the method `List<T>.Remove(T)`, it doesn't remove anything.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    Debug.Log("Clicked for mixing");
    foreach (Element element in ElementsControl.elements)
    {
        if (element.composition.Length > 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("FINE. Element is not pure");
            List<Element> a = new List<Element>();
            foreach (Element compElement in element.getRawComposition())
            {
                a.Add(compElement);
            }
            string allComposition = "";
            foreach (Element dispElement in a)
            {
                if (allComposition == "")
                    allComposition = dispElement.name;
                else
                    allComposition += " + " + dispElement.name;
            }
            Debug.Log(element.name + " composition is: " + allComposition);
            string cauldElements = "";
            foreach (Element cauldElem in cauldron.getElements())
            {
                if (cauldElements == "")
                    cauldElements = cauldElem.name;
                else
                    cauldElements += " + " + cauldElem.name;
            }
            Debug.Log("Cauldron has: " + cauldElements);
            if (ContainsAllItems(cauldron.getElements(), a))
            {
                Debug.Log("OK. Mix result is " + element.name + ", used " + a);
                Debug.Log("Removing " + a.Count + " elements from cauldron");
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (Element remElem in a)
                {
                    cauldron.getElements().Remove(remElem);
                    Debug.Log("Removed " + remElem + " from cauldron");
                    counter++;
                }
                Debug.Log("Removed " + counter + " elements from cauldron");
                Debug.Log("Adding " + element + " to cauldron");
                cauldron.getElements().Add(element);
                return;
            }
            else
                Debug.Log("NO. Mix result not ok");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes in these lines:

```
foreach (Element remElem in a)
{
  cauldron.getElements().Remove(remElem);
  Debug.Log("Removed " + remElem + " from cauldron");
  counter++;
}
```

When I try to delete it, the list stays as it, without deleting anything.

Comment: What is element? Have you debug it and made sure that the same element exists in the list?

Comment: `cauldron.getElements()` probably creates a new list which is then discarded.

Comment: Inn your code it will be removed only in case when `remElem.Equals(compElement) == true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete anything because `remElem` is reference in `a` but you delete it from another list. Even if objects has same values, the references are different. There is no reference equal to `remElem` in `cauldron.getElements()`.

You should write some query to do it:

```
cauldron.getElements().RemoveAll((e) => e.Id == remElem.Id); // or other field or fields
```

You should find object that has same values as `remElem` in `cauldron.getElements()` and then delete it from that list.

But it deletes all elements.

To delete only one you should do:

```
var list = cauldron.getElements();
foreach (Element remElem in a)
{
    var elems = list.Where((e) => e.Id == remElem.Id);
    if (elems.Any())
    {
        list.Remove(elems.ElementAt(0));
        Debug.Log("Removed " + remElem + " from cauldron");
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that solved it, but it deletes all matching elements in list, and, I want just to remove 2 called hydrogen, and 1 called oxygen, and when I try to add 2 oxygen, and 2 hydrogen, and I call the remove, it deletes all 4 elements, not the 3 I want.

Comment: This is the Element class: